# Consumo excesivo de CPU en server Debian 10

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, cpu

Buenas cómo va? en la empresa que trabajo tenemos un servidor Debian 10 con 16 CPU y 32 GB de ram el cual es utilizado como DB con postgres. Hace unas semanas que venimos experimentando un consumo excesivo de CPU, el cual no se lo puedo atribuir a las conexiones recurrentes ya que el server con, por ejemplo, 40 conexiones sigue teniendo un consumo de CPU del 99%, osea tiene el mismo consumo con 40 conexiones como con 300. Tampoco es por trafico de red, y los únicos procesos que veo que se ejecutan son los de las consultas a la DB, ya no se por donde busca. Alguna idea?

Saludos!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienen tareas de optimización recurrente y/o reorganizaciones de los índices de tus tablas en las diferentes bases de datos. Las aplicaciones que se conectan manejan adecuadamente las conexiones!? El estado de los discos duros!?

Answer (score 0):

me paso lo mismo pero fue en mi pc. Te digo lo que hice.
En primer lugar pon este comando en el terminal. Es para actualizar los paquetes, la mayoria de veces soluciona el problema.

```
sudo apt update
```

Y luego coloca este otro.

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Con esto pude solucionar tu problema.
Espero que te ayude.
Salu2.